# TypeError: send_mail() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, multithreading, email

I have an application in my Django project that sends e-mail asynchronously while running server if temperature is more than maximum temperature . Actually as a begining, I am sending to only one recipient and i am comparing temperature received from foo function to a constant one.

But it didn't send e-mails neither asynchronously nor when I access to this application url it returns an error saying :

> TypeError: send_mail() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

mail/views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from threading import Thread
from cap import foo 

class EmailThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, subject, content, from_email):
        self.subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'subject')
        self.content = request.POST.get('content', 'attention ! la temperature a depasse le maximum ')
        self.from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '*****@gmail.com')
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):

        if subject and content and from_email:
            try:
                send_mail(subject, content, from_email, [ '******@gmail.com' ])
                return HttpResponse('templates/mail.html')
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('mail')
        else:

            return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
def send_mail(subject, content, recipient):
    x = foo()
    if x >= 12 :
        EmailThread(subject, content, recipient).start()
```

Comment: You're redefining `send_mail` and probably breaking it somewhere else since you're importing it from `django.core.mail` and defining it yourself

Answer (score 0):

As that comment above says, you're redefining send_mail. I got into this mess as I switched from a plugin email send function, to the native django one, and forgot that my original function was called send_mail.